# For a cyclic Sylow p subgroup of a group G, when is $C_{G}(P)$ = $P$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $P$ is a Sylow p subgroup of a group $G$ and that $P$ is cyclic and P is not a normal subgroup of G.  Does $C_{G}(P)$ = $P$?  Clearly $P$ is contained in its centralizer since $P$ is abelian.  If not are there sufficient conditions for this to be true?  I came upon this while looking at automorphism groups of elementary abelian groups.  In that setting the order of the elementary abelian group is $q^{n}$ and $p$ divides $q^{n} - 1$ with the order of $q$ mod $p$ = $n$.

Comment: It is not always true that $C_G(P)=P$: try $G$ cyclic of order $6$. It would be easier to answer if you could say what kinds of sufficient conditions you are looking for. For example, if $G \le S_{|P|}$ (symmetric group of degree $|P|$) then $C_G(P)=P$.

Comment: Now try $p=2$ and $G=N_{S_7}(C_7)$. $C_G(P)=N_G(P)$ has order 6, and $P$ is not normal.

Comment: Thanks.  I was actually thinking of the case when P is not a normal subgroup of G.  The groups I was looking at are GL(n,q) where q is a prime and p divides $q^{n} - 1$.

Comment: Take $n=2$, $q=5$, $p=3$.

Comment: The self-centralizing thing for GL is for maximal tori, not for their Sylow p-subgroups. You are probably just getting confused since for some small examples the k'th cyclotomic polynomial in q is a prime power. For n=1, the two tori are order q+1 and order q-1. They are self-centralizing, but any (not too trivial) subgroup has the entire torus as its centralizer too.

Comment: Thanks @JackSchmidt That clears thinks up nicely.

Comment: @GregGibson: There is an proposion for $p$ groups,Let $G$ be a $p$ group and $A$ be maximal normal abelian subgroup of $G$ then $C_{(G)}(A)=A$.

Comment: @GregGibson: sorry it is not what you are looking for.